Apply function rowwise() using column names to identify function arguments using mutate()
I've created a tibble where each column is named to correspond to the arguments of a custom function.  There are many columns and so I'm trying to avoid having to explicitly call and assign each argument.  I've blindly been trying different syntaxes but to no avail.  If some one could help me, I would appreciate it.
Here's a MWE:
# Define simple function
myFunc <- function(a, b, c) a*b^c

# Create tibble of parameters (intentionally out of order)
tbl <- tibble(b = 2:6, a = 1:5, c = -1:3)

# Apply function by listing columns explicitly
tbl |> rowwise() |> mutate(myFunc(a = a, b= b, c=c))

# Fail to apply function...
tbl |> rowwise() |> mutate(myFunc())

# Fail again...
tbl |> rowwise() |> mutate(myFunc(.data))
# Continue ad nauseum...



Are you willing to add ... to your function definition?

@the-mad-statter Yes!

One option would be to use the purrr::pmap family of functions, e.g. using pmap_dbl you could do:
myFunc <- function(a, b, c) a * b^c

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)

tbl <- tibble(b = 2:6, a = 1:5, c = -1:3)

tbl %>%
  mutate(res = pmap_dbl(., myFunc))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>       b     a     c    res
#>   <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     2     1    -1    0.5
#> 2     3     2     0    2  
#> 3     4     3     1   12  
#> 4     5     4     2  100  
#> 5     6     5     3 1080


OMG that's so simple and elegant, yet I'm not able to get this to work in the more complex situation I am trying execute.  In the more complex example the function has default arguments and returns a tibble, not a double.  As a result I tried the syntax  pmap(., myMoreComplexFunction), .keep = "none") I get the error  `! object '.' not found.  Any idea why?

Ahh I figured out why the above syntax failed.  I was using the |> pipe into mutate rather than %>%.  Now it runs!!!

Your last two invocations fail because myFunc expects three vectors, not zero arguments or a single data.frame.
You can change it to make the last invocation work by giving it an argument that receives the data pronoun .data:
myFunc <- function(x) x$a * x$b ^ x$c

tbl |> rowwise() |> mutate(myFunc(.data))

Beware that .data isn’t a regular data.frame, so you cannot use x as if it were.

perhaps the custom function is used for different purposes and need not be changed.

@Onyambu I’m expecting that, actually. But you can always wrap it.

I'd prefer not doing that, but out of curiosity... how would you wrap it?

@mikemtnbikes Well, myFuncWrapper = function (x) myFunc(x$a, x$b, x$c).

We can use !!! as shown:
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

myFunc <- function(a, b, c) a*b^c
tbl <- tibble(b = 2:6, a = 1:5, c = -1:3)

tbl %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(my = myFunc(!!!syms(set_names(names(.))))) %>%
  ungroup

giving
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      b     a     c     my
  <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
1     2     1    -1    0.5
2     3     2     0    2  
3     4     3     1   12  
4     5     4     2  100  
5     6     5     3 1080  


Nice example! The syntax is more complex than the accepted answer, but is helping me understand !!! better.

Yes but the accepted answer does not answer the question as stated which was how to "Apply function rowwise()" .

True, but that's a pretty trivial tweak.  Still I'll add it.

You could use any of the following and cbind to the data:
do.call(myFunc, tbl)
[1]    0.5    2.0   12.0  100.0 1080.0

exec(myFunc, !!!tbl)
[1]    0.5    2.0   12.0  100.0 1080.0

NB: What if tbl had more columns some of which are not defined in the function? Then use:
eval(body(myFunc), tbl)
[1]    0.5    2.0   12.0  100.0 1080.0

Note that the following  fails:
tbl$d <- 10
do.call(myFunc, tbl)
Error in (function (a, b, c)  : 
  unused argument (d = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10))

tbl %>%
+     mutate(res = pmap_dbl(., myFunc))
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `res = pmap_dbl(., myFunc)`.
Caused by error in `pmap_dbl()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `.f()`:
! unused argument (d = .l[[4]][[i]])
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

eval(body(myFunc), tbl) # THIS RUNS
[1]    0.5    2.0   12.0  100.0 1080.0


Lastly, the safest way is to modify the formals of the function by the data directly. This is to ensure that if there are default values within the function, these values are maintained while those in the list are changed. Note that the eval(body(fun), ...) might fail if the function had default values. Use the code below
tbl$e <- "nothing"
do.call(myFunc, modifyList(a<-formals(myFunc), tbl)[names(a)])
[1]    0.5    2.0   12.0  100.0 1080.0

NB:
In case your function is not vectorized (which is rarely the case with most R functions) then invoke mapply
do.call(mapply, c(myFunc, modifyList(a<-formals(myFunc), tbl)[names(a)]))
[1]    0.5    2.0   12.0  100.0 1080.0


Your answer is ignoring the rowwise() invocation. It doesn’t matter for the example function provided by OP but I’m assuming it was present for a reason.

@KonradRudolph rowwise is for vectorization. It has no effect if the function is itself vectorized.

Yes, that’s the point: presumably OP’s function isn’t vectorised.

@KonradRudolph I meant my other solutions. I deleted the pmap once i realized it was posted. Yours will pass since you modified the function. Sorry bout that.
